# Redirect home URL to Magento folder

Tags: magento, url

I have Magento installed on my site at mydomain.com/magento. I'm happy with it to stay in this directory, however when people visit the site directly (i.e. mydomain.com) I would like this to open the Magento folder. How can I do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your setup, it's hard to give you exact advice, but searching for url redirects will give you a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your server redirect "mydomain.com" to the directory you have installed Magento at. If you are using apache you could add a virtualhost like the one below to your httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "/yourpath/magento"
CustomLog "/tmp/access_log" common
LogLevel debug
ErrorLog "/tmp/error.log"

<Directory "/yourpath/magento">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews Indexes
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    # Rewrites to allow links
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # We are not allowing any directive contained in a .htaccess file 
    AllowOverride None
    # We grant all permissions
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, sorry I'm very new to this, would I find that file in the root of the domain FTP?